# All values in a 5x5 Super Minesweeper grid

Tags: combinatorics, minesweeper

In a Super™ Minesweeper grid each cell is either a mine or a value. A value in row $r$ and column $c$ represents the total number of mines located in row $r$ or column $c$.

Can you fill a 5x5 Super™ Minesweeper grid with mines such that every number from 0 to 6 appears at least once? Good luck!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One possible answer is:

> [image]
>
>  The zero and six force most of the grid, then the 54 is another significant constraint.

Comment: Correct and well done!

Comment: _A value in row `r` and column `c` represents the total number of mines located in row `r` **or** column `c`_. Doesn't your solution use _[...] row **and** column_?

Comment: @alex I puzzled over that too. But if you use that definition 6 can never be used, so I inferred that this was what the OP had in mind.

Comment: Oh, actually true. Thanks for clarification.